Existence of an unique solution of an ODE without boundary conditions
I would like to ask how to determine if there is a unique solution to an ODE that does not have any boundary conditions, nor initial conditions. It sounds weird but I wanted to know if there is a case where an unique solution still exists.
For example, consider a one dimensional ODE where its solution $q(x)$ satisfies the following equation,
$A(x) \cdot q''(x) + B(x) \cdot q'(x) + C(x) \cdot q(x) + D(x) = 0$
where $A(x), B(x), C(x), D(x)$ are all non-zero functions of $x$.
And if the unique solution exists, what would be a way to solve it (I was thinking of FEM but it requires boundary conditions for most cases).

Following is a rough intuition of what I have thought of so far.

Intuitively, when it is a zeroth order derivative operator ($A(x) = B(x) = 0$), solution of the ODE $q(x)$ is determined as
$q(x) = -\frac{D(x)}{C(x)}$
and it is unique. Also for the first order derivative operator ($A(x) = 0$), $q(x)$ is determined as a solution of
$B(x) \cdot q'(x) + C(x) \cdot q(x) + D(x) = 0$
If $D(x) = 0$, we can claim that the solution is not unique, however, it is not the case.

Since these equation are linear, the question of uniqueness can be reduced to whether the $D=0$ case has a unique solution since any such solution can be added to the solution of the equation with any other $D$ and still satisfy the differential equation.
